# Fetching data from mongo-meteor collection is not working inside react useTracker Hook

Tags: javascript, mongodb, meteor, react-hooks

I'm new to meteor and I'm following the meteor react tutorial to create an app that organizes To do (https://react-tutorial.meteor.com/simple-todos/03-forms-and-events.html), I've followed everything to the letter but for some reason the useTracker hook to render is not working and I don't get any error. The app is supposed to look like this:

[App from meteor tutorial](https://i.stack.imgur.com/7TzbX.png)

But is looking like this in my local, as you can see any task is there, probably this is caused by the useTracker Hook in the main.js or the collection.

[My local](https://i.stack.imgur.com/5VqTt.png)

My App.jsx file is equal to the tutorial, here is the file:

```
import React from 'react';
import { useTracker } from 'meteor/react-meteor-data';
import { Task } from './Task';
import { TasksCollection } from '/imports/api/TasksCollection';
import { TaskForm } from './TaskForm';

export const App = () => {
  const tasks = useTracker(() => TasksCollection.find({}, { sort: { createdAt: -1 } }).fetch());

  return (
    <div>
      <h1>To do App!</h1>

      <TaskForm/>

      <ul>
        { tasks.map(task => <Task key={ task._id } task={ task }/>) }
      </ul>
    </div>
  );
};
```

The tasks variable is returning an empty array [] and the mongo db database is not empty in the server, but maybe is empty in the client, the thing is weird because I have exactly the same files as the repository of the tutorial: https://github.com/meteor/react-tutorial

And here i initialize the mongo collection:

```
import { Mongo } from 'meteor/mongo';

export const TasksCollection = new Mongo.Collection('tasks');
```

In summary I dont know what to do, and if the error is caused by the collection in the client or maybe the use tracker is not working properly.

My main.js is:

```
import { Meteor } from 'meteor/meteor';
import { TasksCollection } from '/imports/api/TasksCollection';

const insertTask = taskText => TasksCollection.insert({ text: taskText });

Meteor.startup(() => {
  if (TasksCollection.find().count() === 0) {
    [
      'Do web page for father',
      'Do the list for the trip ',
      'Play Cod with the friends',
      'Go to the gym',
      'Make an unicorn company',
      'Help people in need',
      'Buy some clothes',
    ].forEach(insertTask);
  }
});
```

I tried to fetch the data in the mongo db collection and I expected the documents but I received an empty array, also y tried to use withTracker instead os useTracker but it didn't work.

Comment: Can you also show the the code where you are subscribing to this collection?

Comment: I'm not subscribing to the collection because in the tutorial they didn't, and i thought it should work without the subscribe.

Answer (score 4):

The tutorial is correct. All scripts work well. What is needed is to to follow instructions correctly. The reason for such an **"error"** would be if you used `'meteor create simple-todos-react'` instead of **'meteor create simple-todos-react --prototype'** in the beginning. The **'--prototype'** option adds the **'autopublish'** package in the project structure. If you don't use the '--prototype' option then you will need to run 'meteor add autopublish' in the your project folder later when it comes to the **TaskCollection** step.

Answer (score 0):

The problem was my "packages" file, I didn't have the option "autopublish" so the data from the server it was not being sent to my client I just put the autopublish and everything works.

Comment: Is autopublish the only option? What is ther other solution in a production app where autopublish is removed?